# Firestore Data validation for number of parameters to be written

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've a `HashMap` which has 2 parameters which I want to add in `Firestore Database`.

```
    FirebaseFirestore mFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();    
    Map<String,Object> userItemsMap=new HashMap<>();    
            userItemsMap.put("EmailAddress",user.getEmail());
            userItemsMap.put("CostPrice",thaliBO.getCostPrice()); 
 mFirestore.collection("Maharashtra/411057/"+user.getUid()).add(userItemsMap)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                            String str="hi";
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    String str="hi";
                }
            });
```

I'm validating data using the `Firestore` rules as:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{state}/{zip}/{uid}/{document=**} {  
allow write: if request.resource.data.CostPrice>0 &&
request.resource.data.EmailAddress.size()<30 
        }
      }
   }
```

I'm concerned for a situation where someone using reverse engineering add some more parameters to the `userItemsMap` like

```
userItemsMap.put("PhoneNUmber","123456789");
```

which will be stored in the `firestore` consuming unnecessary memory.

Is there any data validation rule in `firestore` which can prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `resource` variable as you are already doing.

With the `data` property of the `resource` you get a `rules.Map`, i.e. a Map of the document data.

The `Map` type has the `keys()` and `size()` methods , see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map.

Then, you just have to check that:

```
request.resource.data.size() == 2
```

and

that the `keys` are corresponding to `EmailAddress` and `CostPrice`. For that, you will use the `hasOnly()` method of the `keys`, since the `keys()` method returns a `rules.List`, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List. So do as follows:

```
request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['EmailAddress', 'CostPrice']) == true
```

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks for the help :)